# I am using Google App Scripts SpreadSheet.openById(), but it assumes Sheet0 as active sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a trigger to get id when there is a change in sheet selection which is working fine when each google sheet has its own google app script, but I want to create a google app script which will work for every sheet based on spreadsheet-id.

So I tried running a function that has SpreadSheet.openById("SpreadSheet_id) from the Google Apps Script Editor, but it assumes the active sheet to be Sheet0 by default, even though the sheet that is open in my Google Sheets is Sheet1, and therefore returns incorrect things.

Is there any some other method, or solution to above problem I am facing?

This is the code I am using.

```
function getActiveSheetByURL(id) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getActiveSheet();
  console.log(ss.getSheetId());
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't include enough details to let others know what are you doing. Google Apps Script doesn't include `SpreadSheet` as a reserved name, so you should explain what it is. It's a common practice to include sample code, usually referred to as minimal complete example or minimal complete and verifiable example (mcve) as text, the textual error message, / logs.

Comment: You might save a lot of time if you **study** https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. Please note that this briefly mentions some basic tasks like reading and writing values from and to a spreadsheet. I also mention very relevant concepts and points to other documents.  Please note that besides this guide there are more resources, including **quickstarts** that are examples used to show how to apply the concepts and to do typical tasks.

Comment: Going back to this specific question, the question should include enough details to understand why you are using `openById(id)` instead of `getActiveSpreadsheet()` or why you are not using `getActiveSheet()` if what you are looking is to get the the active sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling the function from a spreadsheet trigger, instead of using `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)` to get the active sheet, you should use the event object.

To learn about the event objects in Google Apps Script, go to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

All the Spreadsheet event objects have a `source` property that returns the Class Spreadsheet object corresponding to the active spreadsheet.
The Edit event object also includes the `range` property corresponding to the edited range.

Using the on-edit installable trigger, use the `range` property with the `getSheet()` method.

```
function respondToEdit(e){
   const sheet = e?.range.getSheet();
   console.log(sheet?.getName() ?? 'Remember, this should be called by a on edit trigger');
}
```

NOTES

`null` will be assigned to `e` when the function is run by clicking the Run button. Because of this, I use `?.` , `??` and a custom message to handle accidental executions.

- `?.` is the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).
- `??` is the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing).

You might try to use `source` instead of `range`, but in such case, use `getActiveSheet()`. Theoretically, this should work too. I feel more confident about using the edit method because it is only triggered by edit events, while other events might start the change method and require more complex handling.

---

`SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)` is unaware of the trigger / execution context other than the authorization to be executed; it gets an independent spreadsheet instance without the user selection information to return the first cell as the active range. Hence, the first sheet is returned as the active sheet, no matter how this method was called.